# How can I define private variables in a Grails config file?

Tags: variables, grails, configuration

We can reuse properties that are defined in a Grails config file. A simple example:

```
accountFake = '12345678901234567890'
accountValid = '09876543210987654321'

environments {
    development {
        payments.info.transfer.accountNumber = "${accountFake}"
    }
    test {
        payments.info.transfer.accountNumber = "${accountFake}"
    }
    preproduction {
        payments.info.transfer.accountNumber = "${accountFake}"
    }
    production {
        payments.info.transfer.accountNumber = "${accountValid}"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to define the scope of this variable as private? I don’t want these variables to be read outside of the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them into declarations rather than binding assignments by adding `def`:

```
def accountFake = '12345678901234567890'
```

This makes it a local variable within the config script and does not include the value in the final `grailsApplication.config`